# Transaction count after EXECUTE a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, transactions, sql-server-2012-express

```
Create Proc A
    as
    begin
        Begin try
         --Logic Here
         Execute B
        end try
        begin catch
        end catch
    End
```

Above is my two sp's

I am calling SP **B** from SP **A**. 
there are two different databases present in the different location.
A sp is in one location & B sp is in other location. both the SP are connected through linked server.

when I am calling **SP A** from Webservice.

In the web service I have written the logic for transactions.
I have not written any logic for transactions in the SQL.

In the SP B there is no logic is written it simply returning one value.
Linked server communication is working for all other SP's.
I am really very frustrated why this error is coming for only one SP.

Answer (score 0):

It could be cause by a few issues. Try the below script in your CATCH block.

```
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @error INT, 
       @message VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    RAISERRROR ('Issue', 16, 1, @error, @message)
END CATCH
```